# The most obvious review audit

Tags: support, review-audits

[This audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7253336) is mistagged as `spam` (counter to purpose of `spam` tag) and has a comment on it saying that it is spam. It might serve to remove those.

Comment: This is why users shouldn't be editing spam. Not even the tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You gotta admit, it'd be pretty embarrassing if someone failed that audit... Gotta wonder about the joker who voted to close instead of flagging though.

I've removed the <s>most obvious</s> completely unnecessary meta-indicators on the off-chance that it's assigned to anyone else as an audit.

Comment: If you're in the triage queue and you receive a spam question that you've already flagged as spam before it doesn't let you flag as spam again. That's why I've voted to close spam from triage before.

Comment: Ah, yeah - that shouldn't be happening anymore.