# Received an audit in Triage that I previously flagged as spam

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, triage

I received this obvious [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7394374) in the Triage queue, which should obviously be flagged as spam, so I clicked on *Unsalvageable* which popped up this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I already flagged this question as spam before, so it wouldn't allow me to flag it as spam again. So to pass this obvious audit I just voted to close which allowed me to pass the audit and continue on down the queue.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

According to [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287508/the-most-obvious-review-audit/287511#comment162565_287511) I shouldn't be receiving audit questions that I've already flagged before, as officially stated in this [status-completed-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286415).

Comment: I can confirm, I've seen this happen before as well.

Comment: OT: I can't believe someone can write an advert like that. Good choice of tags however :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found one more spot where the filtering for spam posts needed to be added.  I have pushed that to dev and it should be live in the next build.  Let me know if you continue to see this happening.

Comment: Not sure if the next build has gone out or not, but I just hit this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7438996.

Comment: Just happened to me: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8340218

Comment: Just got one too: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9168657