# Late Answers audit is a post I had already flagged before it became an audit

Tags: bug, review-audits, late-answers

I encountered an [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/27939771) in Late Answers, a link-only answer, of a post I had already flagged back as VLQ when it was first posted. The flag dialog reminded me of that by showing that the VLQ option was no longer available to me:

[image: Audit flag dialog]

This was reported as a problem earlier on MSE:

[Low Quality Posts you Have Already Flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193128)

It had occurred in LQP and was tagged [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) in January 2019, the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321896) also saying:

> This filter was also updated on some other queues that were missing it.

I'm not sure if this includes Late Answers. It's not the first time it happened to me. It actually happened at least 3 to 4 times before. Maybe even also in First Posts but I'm not 100% sure.

---

There are some MSO bug reports, also tagged [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) that predate it by years:

- [Known Bad "Spam" audits using posts you already flagged as spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320397/11682469)
- [Received an audit in Triage that I previously flagged as spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288314/11682469)

Comment: By the way, [that should be flagged as NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), not VLQ...

Comment: It doesn't make any practical difference, @Tomerikoo; moderators interpret and handle the VLQ and NAA flags identically. Both mean, "this post has fundamental quality problems (that cannot be corrected with community edits) and needs to be deleted".

Comment: @Tomerikoo Quoting another moderator ([Machavity in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50366416#50366416)): "So if you think the OP can edit the post into shape (and link-only is the most likely to do so in my experience) then use VLQ".

Comment: @CodyGray so why have both?

Comment: @JeanneDark But the VLQ description says: *"This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing..."*

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good question. That's been asked and discussed many times. Virtually the entire moderator team at the time of last check is in favor of merging them together, but it hasn't happened yet, because that requires staff to make a significant design change.

Comment: Yes, you should only raise a VLQ flag on a post when it cannot be salvaged via edits. In this case, I would prefer that that attempt at an answer be salvaged with an edit rather than a flag. (That said, mods will generally delete these answers in response to flags, because we don't have time to edit each of them. If they are later edited, they can be undeleted. But I'd really prefer that reviewers did the editing whenever possible, and only flag when there's really no way to salvage the content.)

Comment: @Tomerikoo The flag description could be improved, but notice the word "unlikely" which doesn't rule it out. There are rare cases in which link-only answers are actually edited into shape. In case of NAA, the flag status doesn't change (I retracted it when I noticed it once), but a VLQ flag is marked as helpful. [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364979/11682469) with an answer by a former SE employee is also relevant.